# Any way to run through a loop on a group by group basis, resetting the variables after each group has gone through in SQL?

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql, while-loop, database-cursor

The basis of what I am trying to do is basically have the loop I've created run through my table but by group, (which would be to run by each Manager and then reset the variables and run and do so until no more managers exist).

**Below is the Code used for the CURSOR Loop:**

```
--Setting up table for LOOP 
DECLARE @Running TABLE(BASManagerName VARCHAR(150), YearMonthDay DATE, CommissionAmount NUMERIC(16,2), LeftOverAmount NUMERIC(16,2), RunningTotal NUMERIC(16,2), Threshold INT, Payout NUMERIC(16,2), MyCounter INT)


DECLARE HotelThreshold CURSOR LOCAL
FOR
    SELECT RowGrouping ,BASManagerName ,YearMonthDay ,CommissionAmount
    FROM #HotelSumsNEWYearMonth
    ORDER BY RowGrouping, BASManagerName, YearMonthDay

DECLARE @Rank INT
    ,@CursorManager VARCHAR(150)
    ,@YearMonthDay DATE
    ,@Total NUMERIC(16,2)
    ,@Threshold INT
    ,@LeftOverAmount NUMERIC(16,2)
    ,@RunningTotal NUMERIC(16,2)
    ,@Payout NUMERIC(16,2)
    ,@MyCounter INT

    SET @Total = 0
    SET @LeftOverAmount = 0
    SET @RunningTotal = 0
    SET @MyCounter = 0
    SET @Payout = 0
    SET @Threshold = 0

OPEN HotelThreshold

    FETCH NEXT FROM HotelThreshold INTO @Rank, @CursorManager, @YearMonthDay, @Total
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF CAST((@LeftOverAmount + @Total) / 50000 AS INT) < 1
        BEGIN
            SET @RunningTotal = (@LeftOverAmount + @Total)
            SET @Threshold = 0 
            SET @Payout = 0
            SET @LeftOverAmount = @RunningTotal - (@Threshold * 50000)
            SET @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1 
        END
        ELSE IF CAST((@LeftOverAmount + @Total) / 50000 AS INT) >= 1
        BEGIN
            SET @RunningTotal = (@LeftOverAmount + @Total) 
            SET @Threshold = CASE WHEN CAST(@RunningTotal / 50000 AS INT) >= 1 THEN CAST(@RunningTotal / 50000 AS INT) * 1 ELSE 0 END
            SET @Payout = @Threshold * 2500
            SET @LeftOverAmount = @RunningTotal - (@Threshold * 50000)
            SET @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1 
        END

        INSERT @Running VALUES (@CursorManager, @YearMonthDay, @Total, @LeftOverAmount, @RunningTotal, @Threshold, @Payout, @MyCounter)
        FETCH NEXT FROM HotelThreshold INTO @Rank, @CursorManager, @YearMonthDay, @Total

    END 
CLOSE HotelThreshold
DEALLOCATE HotelThreshold


DROP TABLE #NewRunning
SELECT *
INTO #NewRunning
FROM @Running

SELECT * FROM #NewRunning
```

Here is the DDL of the table #HotelSumsNewYearMonth that populates the Cursor and an example of the data within the table:

[image]

```
+-------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+
| RowGrouping | BASManagerName | YearMonthDay | YearMonth | CommissionAmount |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+
|           1 | Debbie         | 7/1/2019     | 2019-07   |         33508.83 |
|           1 | Debbie         | 8/1/2019     | 2019-08   |         34240.37 |
|           1 | Debbie         | 9/1/2019     | 2019-09   |         19282.73 |
|           1 | Debbie         | 10/1/2019    | 2019-10   |                0 |
|           1 | Debbie         | 11/1/2019    | 2019-11   |                0 |
|           2 | Pam            | 7/1/2019     | 2019-07   |           321.23 |
|           2 | Pam            | 8/1/2019     | 2019-08   |           952.89 |
|           2 | Pam            | 9/1/2019     | 2019-09   |           601.84 |
|           2 | Pam            | 10/1/2019    | 2019-10   |            56.94 |
|           2 | Pam            | 11/1/2019    | 2019-11   |            76.83 |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+
```

**Explanation of what the Loop code is achieving:**

What the loop achieves is that it will create a running total of the commission earned by month by BASManager. However with a clause that if the commission ever reaches over 50K they will receive a 2500 payout for that month. Then what has to happen is that the running total the month after the 50K is achieved I will subtract however many times that threshold is achieved from the running total and keep it rolling from that point on.

Error of the output because the loop just runs for the entire table and not by each group:

```
+----------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| BASManagerName | YearMonthDay | CommissionAmount | LeftOverAmount | RunningTotal | Threshold | Payout | MyCounter |
+----------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| Debbie         | 7/1/2019     |         33508.83 |       33508.83 |     33508.83 |         0 |      0 |         1 |
| Debbie         | 8/1/2019     |         34240.37 |        17749.2 |      67749.2 |         1 |   2500 |         2 |
| Debbie         | 9/1/2019     |         19282.73 |       37031.93 |     37031.93 |         0 |      0 |         3 |
| Debbie         | 10/1/2019    |                0 |       37031.93 |     37031.93 |         0 |      0 |         4 |
| Debbie         | 11/1/2019    |                0 |       37031.93 |     37031.93 |         0 |      0 |         5 |
| Pam            | 7/1/2019     |           321.23 |       37353.16 |     37353.16 |         0 |      0 |         6 |
| Pam            | 8/1/2019     |           952.89 |       38306.05 |     38306.05 |         0 |      0 |         7 |
| Pam            | 9/1/2019     |           601.84 |       38907.89 |     38907.89 |         0 |      0 |         8 |
| Pam            | 10/1/2019    |            56.94 |       38964.83 |     38964.83 |         0 |      0 |         9 |
| Pam            | 11/1/2019    |            76.83 |       39041.66 |     39041.66 |         0 |      0 |        10 |
+----------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

You can see that Debbie's running total is at a correct point at 37031.93, shes already received a payout at 08/01/2019 for reaching over 50,000 and then the left over amount after subtracting the 50,000 from the running total plus the next months commission leaves her total at 37031.93.

**What i want/need to happen is** that once November passes for her, that as soon as the loop starts the run for Pam is to reset the variables back to 0 and start over with Pam's data. However, you can see that currently it is keeping Debbie's runningtotal and using that as a basis to start Pam's calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions!  Cursors are not necessary for this -- nor is most of your extra columns.

```
select t.*,
       (floor(running_commissionamount / 50000) - floor( (running_commissionamount - commissionamount) / 50000)
       ) * 2500 as this_months_commission,
       (running_commissionamount - 
        (floor(running_commissionamount / 50000) - floor( (running_commissionamount - commissionamount) / 50000)
        ) * 50000
       ) as remaining_after_commission
from (select t.*,
             sum(commissionamount) over (partition by rowgrouping order by yearmonth) as running_commissionamount
      from t
     ) t
```

The only real tricky part here is counting the number of 50,000 thresholds that are passed.

Comment: Wow @Gordon Linoff that is insanely close to my needed result however I would need to have it so the after august the running total would need to show as August (running_commissionamount - 50,000 (or however many times that total fully goes into 50K)) + commissionamount for following month so September would show as 37031.93  instead of 87031.93. 

Thank you i will take this code and mess with it to see if I cant get my fully needed result, as the grouping reset portion works!

Comment: @JesusGBC -- probably just need to add month to the grouping.